# How to get an element's name when iterating through elements with forEach in JS?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm iterating through multiple `td` elements using `forEach` and `document.querySelectorAll`. How can I access an element's `name` value within this loop?

This is what I'm trying at the moment, and it's returning undefined.

HTML:

```
<td name="monday" class="from">foobar</td>
<td name="tuesday" class="from">foobar</td>
<td name="wednesday" class="from">foobar</td>
<td name="thursday" class="from">foobar</td>
<td name="friday" class="from">foobar</td>
<td name="saturday" class="from">foobar</td>
<td name="sunday" class="from">foobar</td>
```

JS:

```
const myNodeList =  document.querySelectorAll('.from'); // grabs some td elements
[].forEach.call(myNodeList, function (item) {
    console.log(item.name);
});
```

result:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
console.log(item.name);
```

to :

```
console.log(item.getAttribute("name"))
```